# Carga de imágenes y agregar más imágenes Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con la carga de imágenes y al querer cargar más imágenes me borra las que están cargadas, entiendo que es un comportamiento normal. Como se puede modificar para que el usuario cargue más imágenes en caso de necesitarlo?

**El input de carga:**

```
<input wire:model="imagenes" type="file" name="imagenes" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**Y el foreach de carga:**

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {

            $imagenes = $pathGaleria;
            $nombre = Str::random(10) . $imagenes->getClientOriginalName();

            
            $ruta = public_path() . '\imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre;
            Image::make($pathGaleria)
            ->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->save($ruta);

            $img = imgPropiedades::create([
                'url' => '/imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre,
                'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
            ]);
        }
```

Como puedo hacer que el botón de carga de imágenes no reemplace las imágenes y me permita cargar más? alguien sería tan amable de brindarme una orientación?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor el comportamiento que este código te da?

Comment: En el input selecciono "n" cantidad de imágenes, después las redimensiono con intervention image y las guarda en la carpeta publica imagenesPropiedades. Guardo en la DB la url y el id correspondiente. Si en el input selecciono más imagenes reemplaza a las anteriores y necesito agregar más imágenes no reemplazar.

Answer (score 0):

Tal parece tu problema se debe a que no se generan nombres únicos en las imágenes a la hora de almacenarlas te recomiendo utilizar la siguiente función

> uniqid()

la cual generara un único "id" irrepetible, quedando de la siguiente manera tu código:

```
$ruta = public_path() . '\imagenesPropiedades/' . $nombre . uniqid();
```

Comment: Hola Isaac, el problema está en la vista con livewire, el input file me permite cargar n fotos y si vuelvo a hacer clic sobre el mismo botón en el mismo momento me pisa las imágenes cargadas reemplazando a las viejas imágenes. Lo que estoy buscando es cargar más imágenes sin reemplazar.